# How can I monitor with nagios an unmanaged switch?

Tags: nagios, switch

can i somehow monitor the unmanaged switches? it's not really monitoring if you have to ignore 4 switches..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if it's dumb switch maybe you can ping something attached behind it. there are devices like pingers but you don't even need to buy them. get some old adsl router, turn off dhcp in it, give it static ip address and use nagios to check if the device responds to ping. if not - probably router or a switch hanged.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this out. Or would it be the same, if I create a hostgroup for those servers which are connected with the unmanaged switch?

Comment: @ud - indeed; provided they do not use interface teaming and are only reachable via the switch. what's the model of your 3com switches? maybe they are smart switches - without all the frills brought with manageable devices yet with simple web gui [and pingable too].

Comment: It's an Office Connect Gigabit 16.

Comment: @ud unmanaged indeed.

Comment: Yeah..it's just insane that we use this switch for our most important servers.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is look for SNMP libraries for said switches. But given the fact that they're unmanaged, I think your only option might be to perform a pingtest and that's it.

What brand / type are they ?

Comment: We have here 3Com Gigabit switches.

Comment: A pingtest is not possible when they have no ip address assigned or am I wrong?

Comment: You may want to look up the definition of "unmanaged". SNMP library = managed switch ;) You basically advice someone with a car without engine to get some fuel so the engine can run again.

Comment: You're right, wasn't thinking clearly.